# Count array elements which keys are numeric

Tags: php, arrays

I have quite a strange array:

```
Array
(
   [title] => title
   [weight] => 0
   [0] => Text1
   [1] => Text2
   [additional] => Info
}
```

How do I count array elements which keys are numeric (only)?

Comment: i would imagine any solution will require a loop

Comment: @Randy what is the problem with using a loop?

Comment: So no chance to do without loop?

Comment: well 'something' has to analyse each key, so loop must be required. Even if there was a core php function, it would still lopp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'title',
    'weight' => 0,
    0 => 'Text1',
    1 => 'Text2',
    'additional' => 'Info'
);

$keyCount = count(
    array_filter(
        array_keys($data),
        'is_numeric'
    )
);

var_dump($keyCount);
```

**EDIT**

And from PHP version 5.6.0, you can use

```
$keyCount = count(
    array_filter($data, 'is_numeric', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)
);
```

Comment: i want a speed test between the two answers :-)

Comment: @Dagon - then run a speed test between the two answers, I've no idea which is the faster of the two

Comment: I can't even believe how this solution works so great. Thank you so much! Very neat solution!

Comment: clearly i want some one else to do it :-)

Comment: @Randy can you comment on why you don't want it in a loop, given `array_filter()` also [_"Iterates over each value"_](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)?

Comment: @CodeCaster, because the array is huge and most of the keys don't have any value.

Comment: array_filter does a loop, you just don't see it - which is why i wondered if it is any more efficient than using a foreach() loop. All the array keys have a value - or the array would not work.

Comment: Dagon, it is more efficient. This loop is done in C, not PHP. Time difference would be minimal. Can be compared to differences in using single versus double quotes

Comment: I ran a quick workbench on arrays of 3x that size and the foreach was still 20% faster; also, this solution isn't friendly in terms of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Should be quiet simple:

```
$i = 0;
foreach  ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (is_numeric($k))
        $i++;
}
```